# Add layout in table view

Tags: java, android

I created a code in xml, creating a tablelayou using a tablerow, each tablerow has 3 linear layout.
The first linearlayout has width=40dp and height=90dp. the second linearlayout has width=0dp, height=90dp and weight=1, the third linearlayout is equals de first. So I have this result:

[image: xml layout]

So I need to create this same layout on java, I use the same configurations but the alignment was bad. How can I fiz it?, look:

[image]

I put border to show alignment. This is the java code:

```
 int wlienar = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int hlienar = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 90, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int wLienarUserDataBeer = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 0, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int hLienarUserDataBeer = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 90, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int wUserPicture = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int hUserPicture = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int wLogoBeer = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int hLogoBeer = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    int margim = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    Bitmap bmImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.eu);

    iconViewRound.setImageBitmap(bmIcon);
    imageViewRound.setImageBitmap(bmImage);

     /* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.feeds_table);

    GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
    border.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF); //white background
    border.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000); //black border with full opacity

    for(int i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
     /*create a linear layout to user picture*/
        LinearLayout linearUserPicture = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearUserPicture.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearUserPicture.setBackground(border);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wlienar, hlienar);

        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, margim, 0);
       // layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;

        RoundedImageView imageView = new RoundedImageView(this, null);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.eu);
        //setting image position
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(wUserPicture, hUserPicture));

        linearUserPicture.addView(imageView, layoutParams);
        /*create a linear layout to user comments beer*/
        //user name
        TextView textViewUserName = new TextView(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            textViewUserName.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.feeds_user_connected_style);
        } else {
            textViewUserName.setTextAppearance(R.style.feeds_user_connected_style);
        }
        textViewUserName.setText(R.string.user_feed_name);

        // beer in date
        TextView textViewDateBeerIn = new TextView(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            textViewDateBeerIn.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.dateBeeinAndPlace);
        } else {
            textViewDateBeerIn.setTextAppearance(R.style.dateBeeinAndPlace);
        }
        textViewDateBeerIn.setText(R.string.date_beerin);

        // textview beer
        TextView textViewBeer = new TextView(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            textViewBeer.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.beerBeerin);
        } else {
            textViewBeer.setTextAppearance(R.style.beerBeerin);
        }
        textViewBeer.setText(R.string.beerBeerin);

        //textview place beer in
        TextView textViewPlace = new TextView(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            textViewPlace.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.dateBeeinAndPlace);
        } else {
            textViewPlace.setTextAppearance(R.style.dateBeeinAndPlace);
        }
        textViewPlace.setText(R.string.place_beerin);

        //textview place count comments
        TextView textViewCountComments = new TextView(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            textViewCountComments.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.countBeerinComment);
        } else {
            textViewCountComments.setTextAppearance(R.style.countBeerinComment);
        }
        textViewCountComments.setText(R.string.countBeerinComment);

        LinearLayout lienarComponents = new LinearLayout(this);
        lienarComponents.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        lienarComponents.addView(textViewUserName);
        lienarComponents.addView(textViewDateBeerIn);
        lienarComponents.addView(textViewBeer);
        lienarComponents.addView(textViewPlace);
        lienarComponents.addView(textViewCountComments);

        LinearLayout linearUserDataBeer = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearUserDataBeer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearUserDataBeer.setBackground(border);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsUserDataBeer = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, hLienarUserDataBeer,1);
        linearUserDataBeer.addView(lienarComponents, layoutParamsUserDataBeer);
        //logo beer
        /*create a linear layout to logo beer*/
        LinearLayout linearLogoBeer = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLogoBeer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLogoBeer.setBackground(border);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsLogo = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wlienar, hlienar);

        //ImageView Setup
        ImageView imageViewLogoBeer = new ImageView(this);
        imageViewLogoBeer.setLayoutParams(
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        // or ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        wLogoBeer,
                        // or ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        hLogoBeer));

        imageViewLogoBeer.setImageResource(R.mipmap.beerin);
        linearLogoBeer.addView(imageViewLogoBeer, layoutParamsLogo);

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
        tr.setBackground(border);

        tr.addView(linearUserPicture);
        tr.addView(linearUserDataBeer);
        tr.addView(linearLogoBeer);
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    }
```

Comment: have you checked the layout_gravity of the lienarComponents layout? what is it set to?

Comment: oh, and what exactly do you need to do? lienarComponents should fill the entire middle section of the cell, i assume?

Comment: Yes. lienarComponents should fill the entire middle section of the cell

Comment: I dont set gravity in lienarComponents. The idea is add the components in lienarComponents and add lienarComponents in linearUserDataBeer. What do You think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of katzenhut  and my friend Afonso

In my tablerow I have 3 columns, so the first column is number 0, the second is number 1 and the third is number 2, like a array the columns start on 0. So for default the columns in table layout is WRAP_CONTENT, in table layout should be set the column that be MATCH_PARENT, in my case the second column is MATCH_PARENT, so I add this line :

```
tl.setColumnStretchable( 1, true );
```

The alignment stay good, the complete code:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.feeds_table);
    tl.setColumnStretchable( 1, true ); // this line fix the error

      for(int i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
     /*create a linear layout to user picture*/
        LinearLayout linearUserPicture = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearUserPicture.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wlienar, hlienar);

        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, margim, 0);

        RoundedImageView imageView = new RoundedImageView(this, null);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.eu);

        //setting image position
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(wUserPicture, hUserPicture));

        linearUserPicture.addView(imageView, layoutParams);

        /*create a linear layout to user comments beer*/

        //user name
        TextView textViewUserName = new TextView(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            textViewUserName.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.feeds_user_connected_style);
        } else {
            textViewUserName.setTextAppearance(R.style.feeds_user_connected_style);
        }
        textViewUserName.setText(R.string.user_feed_name);

        // beer in date
        TextView textViewDateBeerIn = new TextView(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            textViewDateBeerIn.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.dateBeeinAndPlace);
        } else {
            textViewDateBeerIn.setTextAppearance(R.style.dateBeeinAndPlace);
        }
        textViewDateBeerIn.setText(R.string.date_beerin);

        // textview beer
        TextView textViewBeer = new TextView(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            textViewBeer.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.beerBeerin);
        } else {
            textViewBeer.setTextAppearance(R.style.beerBeerin);
        }
        textViewBeer.setText(R.string.beerBeerin);

        //textview place beer in
        TextView textViewPlace = new TextView(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            textViewPlace.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.dateBeeinAndPlace);
        } else {
            textViewPlace.setTextAppearance(R.style.dateBeeinAndPlace);
        }
        textViewPlace.setText(R.string.place_beerin);

        //textview place count comments
        TextView textViewCountComments = new TextView(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            textViewCountComments.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.countBeerinComment);
        } else {
            textViewCountComments.setTextAppearance(R.style.countBeerinComment);
        }
        textViewCountComments.setText(R.string.countBeerinComment);

        //adicionado os camponentes no linear que irá ajuntar todos no linear principal
        LinearLayout lienarComponents = new LinearLayout(this);
        lienarComponents.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        lienarComponents.addView(textViewUserName);
        lienarComponents.addView(textViewDateBeerIn);
        lienarComponents.addView(textViewBeer);
        lienarComponents.addView(textViewPlace);
        lienarComponents.addView(textViewCountComments);

        LinearLayout linearUserDataBeer = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearUserDataBeer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsUserDataBeer = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, hLienarUserDataBeer);
        linearUserDataBeer.addView(lienarComponents, layoutParamsUserDataBeer);

        //logo beer

        /*create a linear layout to logo beer*/
        LinearLayout linearLogoBeer = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLogoBeer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsLogo = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wlienar, hlienar);

        //ImageView Setup
        ImageView imageViewLogoBeer = new ImageView(this);


        imageViewLogoBeer.setLayoutParams(
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        // or ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        wLogoBeer,
                        // or ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        hLogoBeer));

        imageViewLogoBeer.setImageResource(R.mipmap.beerin);

        linearLogoBeer.addView(imageViewLogoBeer, layoutParamsLogo);

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);

        tr.addView(linearUserPicture);
        tr.addView(linearUserDataBeer);
        tr.addView(linearLogoBeer);
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply LayoutParams to lienarLayout. Set the layout_width to match_parent and it will fill the middle section of the cell. But there is one more issue: The TextViews should push the LinearLayout, but they do not. The problem is that you are constructing all these views without attributes. TextView, for example, has several constructors. For instantiation from code, you should use

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(context, attributeSet);
```

where attributeSet is a AttributeSet(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html). This will allow you to manipulate the TextView in the same ways that you can do in xml. So far, they probably all have a default width and do not clip their content, so everything appears fine. by using the attributeSet, you can control the textviews widths, too.

EDIT::
I see I was wrong, you do supply the LayoutParams in the call to addView().

In this line:

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsUserDataBeer = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, hLienarUserDataBeer,1);
```

You set the width to 0 and the weight to 1, which conflicts with the fact that the other layouts are set to WRAP_CONTENT. 
Try instead:

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsUserDataBeer = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.MATCH_PARENT, hLienarUserDataBeer,0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are right, the way that I used was wrong and I need to set MATCH_PARENT. But to fix it is need a change in table layout too, a friend Afonso teached to do it, bellow I put the code